# How to change templates using websockets?

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, go-html-template

I want to split the page into fragments and use the web sockets to change them without reloading the page.

```
 {{define "index"}}
 {{template "head"}}
  <div class = "scene">
     {{template "main"}}
   </div>

{{template "foot"}}
{{end}}
```

I read the json from the client and find out which page to open.

```
func webSocketHandler(conn *websocket.Conn) {

 data := conn.ReadJSON(&msg)

 if data != nil {
    log.Fatal(data)
    return
 }

  LoadVista(msg.Temp,conn)
}
var (
indexTemplate = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(indexVista,mainVista,headVista,footVista 
))
loginTemplate = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(loginVista))
)

func LoadVista(nameTemplate string, conn *websocket.Conn) {
 switch nameTemplate {
 case "page2":
    templateWsRender(nameTemplate,conn)
 }

}
func templateWsRender(name string,conn *websocket.Conn){
//defer conn.Close()
 var buf  bytes.Buffer
 data := page2Template.ExecuteTemplate(&buf,name,nil)
 if data!=nil{
    log.Fatal(data)
 }
 err := conn.WriteMessage(1,buf.Bytes())
 if err!=nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
 }

}
```

Client code

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7030/ws' )

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
  var message = event.data
  loadVista(message)
}

elem.addEventListener( "click" , sendQuery);
function sendQuery() {
  var page = {
    query_type :"openLink",
    temp: "page"
 }
var event = JSON.stringify(page);

socket.send(event);
}

function loadVista(message) {
//alert(message)
document.getElementById('scene').innerHTML = message.data;
}
```

But the "main" template does not change to the "page 2" template. Give advice on how to properly organize the change of templates using Go + js (webscokets). Thanks!

Comment: When you receive data over the websocket in the client, you use normal DOM manipulation methods to insert or change content in the existing page (such as changing `.innerHTML` on some page element).  You can't use server-side rendering from your client-side webSocket data unless the server is sending you fully formed HTML that you just need to insert into a frame or div.  You could use client-side template rendering and then insert the rendered template into the page if you have the template and rendering library locally in the client.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was guided by the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309020/golang-template-range-for-loop-using-json-from-websocket  but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to specify id.; `<div id= "scene">
     {{template "main"}}
   </div>`

instead `<div class = "scene">
     {{template "main"}}
   </div>`

Because What I'm looking for by Id and not by class.
`document.getElementById('scene').innerHTML = message`